# forcing square with small conditions

Tags: set-theory, forcing

In the paper, [Large cardinals and definable counterexamples to the continuum hypothesis](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1359154), Foreman and Magidor mention a way to force $\square_{\omega_1}$ with countable conditions.  (This is used in Theorem 2.17.)  It not hard to guess what this is and prove it is countably closed and $\omega_2$-c.c. under CH.

**Questions:**

(1) Are a definition of this forcing and proofs of its basic properties explicitly written up anywhere?

(2) Does this generalize to higher cardinals, for example forcing $\square_{\omega_2}$ with $\omega_1$-sized conditions?  It seems complications could arise.

Answer (score 7):

I am recovering from a severe injury in my right arm, so cannot write in length. The short answer is:
1. Yes. This was written up in one of J. Kruger's papers.
2. A generalization of this forcing will introduce a partial square over a fat subset of $\omega_3$. Then you may want to shoot a club through this fat set to get the full square OR you may be able to argue that for the application you have in mind - square over a fat set suffices.

Comment: Your right arm is right, but now you are left with just your left. Is it right? Are you left with just your left? And if you have more than just the left left, who is right, right? Certainly not your arm.

Comment: Thanks!  When you can, please let me know which paper of Krueger.

Comment: @Monroe I can't remember, but you can ask John. He is also interested in shooting clubs through fat sets via small conditions. A description of the Foreman-Magidor poset is also available here: https://www.uea.ac.uk/~h020/square_omega_1.pdf

Comment: @Karagila Apparently, too many hours in front of a computer made you forget that you are communicating with human beings.

Comment: Such notion of forcing is now available on Section 3.3 of: http://www.assafrinot.com/paper/31

Answer (score 5):

The appropriate reference for a forcing for adding a square sequence with countable conditions is: "S-forcing I. A "black-box" theorem for morasses, with applications to super-Souslin trees", Shelah and Stanley, Israel J. Math, vol. 43, no. 3, 1982. See section 4 example 1 pages 203-204.